# Length property returns one result less on object array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to loop through an object array but the length property always returns one result less. When I have one dataset, I get 0. When I add another similar dataset, I get 1.

```
var currDatasets = $(this).data('graph').data.datasets;
console.log(currDatasets);
console.log(currDatasets.length);
// shows '0'
var test = [{ label: 'blah', value: 'blah' }];
console.log(test.length);
// shows '1'
```

The console output doesn't really differ from the lower result, except that *{...}* is missing from the [ ]-brackets. However when I use the length property, console.log returns 0.

This is what the console outputs with one datatag:

[image: console result]

And this is what it outputs with two datatags:

[image: console result]

Comment: `[{ label: 'blah', value: 'blah' }]` is an array of 1, containing 2 properties. It's different from: `[{ label: 'blah'}, {value: 'blah' }]`

Comment: I'm going to bet you're using Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, true. Is this a browser related issue?

Comment: use this example: [stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I guess `datasets` variable is changing over time after you printed to the console. And when you expand that array data in your console, it gets its different value by reference. Try to clone `$(this).data('graph').data.datasets` data by using `slice(0)` and print it to the console

Comment: The problem isn't particularly related to the length property. The array seems to contain one item less than expected. I used length as an example.